# Accessing a USB device in phone in absence of compatible drivers / modules

Tags: usb-host-mode, emulators

My android device has an MTK6797 Soc(Xiaomi Redmi note 4x mtk version), and the company never released the kernel source, now I want to connect a USB device through OTG and control it from a chrooted Linux environment inside android, the problem is that the precompiled kernel that ships with the android device doesn't include the driver for the USB device, the kernel also has `CONFIG_MODULES` disabled so I can't compile the driver as a module and load it to the kernel, so now my only option is to run a completely emulated Linux VM(kernel and userspace) inside android and connect the USB device to the VM and load the required module from there(just like you would do on a PC with something like Virtual Box).

The problem is that I can't find an arm emulator that runs on android, I found [Limbo PC emulator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/limbopcemulator/) which is based on Qemu but it emulates X86 and not arm, running an X86 VM inside Limbo PC is very slow so I instead I want to run Arm VM hopefully that would provide a bit of performance push compared to emulating X86.

I can't seem to find any thing that can emulate Arm inside android, Qemu is an open source project so It's hard to imagine that no one ever though of running Qemu arm emulator inside Android.

Regards

Comment: Have you checked this source code release? https://github.com/MT6797

Comment: @Robert Yes I've already compiled https://github.com/MT6797/kernel-3.18 and tried to run it on my device and no joy, the source doesn't contain the config and device tree for my device, and even if I spent two week trying to get it to boot by decompiling  and reverse engineer as much as i could from the original kernel I will probably be disappointed eventually by the lack of some critical driver (e.g touchscreen driver).

Comment: Hello. I have edited the title to point out the actual problem, instead of going in XY direction of finding an emulator. On a side note, can anyone tell me if this is even possible for a VM (assuming on a PC) to access a USB device for which the host machine OS has no drivers to  communicate?